# JSON data error-PHP

Tags: php, json

Am trying to run the below mentioned php code, But it errors out.

PHP code:

```
<?php

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->citationStyles = $this->sm->get('CitationstyleConversion\Model\Citationstyles');
        $this->resetTestData();
    }

    public function testSubmitActionCannotBeAccessedLoggedOut()
    {
        $this->dispatch($this->buildQuery('submit', array(), false));
        $this->assertResponseStatusCode(403);
    }

    public function testSubmitAction()
    {
        $styleMap = $this->citationStyles->getStyleMap();
        $keys = array_keys($styleMap);
        $data = array(
            'fileName' => "Testfile.txt",
            'fileContent' => base64_encode('Test Content'),
            'citationStyleHash' => $keys[0],
        );
        $this->dispatch($this->buildQuery('submit', $data));
        $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
        $response = json_decode($this->getResponse()->getContent());
        print_r($response);  //to print the json result
        $this->assertTrue(is_object($response));
        $this->assertSame($response->status, 'success');
        $this->assertNotEmpty($response->id);
    }
```

Error:

PHPUnit 3.7.29 by Sebastian Bergmann.

```
Configuration read from /home/quotequadsco/public_html/xmlps/phpunit.xml

.................FstdClass Object
(
[error] => File name (fileName) parameter is missing.
[status] => error
[flashMessages] => Array
(
)

)

Time: 4.17 seconds, Memory: 43.00Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) ApiTest\Controller\ApiControllerTest::testSubmitAction
Failed asserting that two strings are identical.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-error
+success

/home/quotequadsco/public_html/xmlps/module/Api/test/ApiTest/Controller/JobControllerTest.php:64

FAILURES!
Tests: 18, Assertions: 56, Failures: 1.
```

Am not sure where am doing wrong in the code. I have parameter "fileName" but errors says fileName is missing. I don't have any clue how to solve it.Pls help me!

Comment: The only assertion about 2 strings being identical is `$this->assertSame($response->status, 'success');`. It appears that the response status was `error`. You need to examine your `$response` variable to see what went wrong.

Comment: output of `$response` is `stdClass Object
(
[error] => File name (fileName) parameter is missing.
[status] => error
[flashMessages] => Array
(
)

)`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't looking very carefully at the output! How does the service you're testing process the request? Maybe it's a bug in that service, because, as you say, `fileName` does appear to be being populated. Without details of the code behind the service you're testing, I doubt anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: Am trying to run a shell program,from where this php code is called.Am getting error only in this code with no clue to solve it.